# Application doesnt start on some devices, even when there is no error

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I have an app on play store, some users are not able to open the app. It results in a crash as soon as it is opened. I checked the Play store CRASH & ANR report and found the following error:

```
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2977)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3114)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:113)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1859)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6831)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.tracecost.NotificationReceivedActivity.getActivities (NotificationReceivedActivity.java:163)
  at com.tracecost.NotificationReceivedActivity.onCreate (NotificationReceivedActivity.java:147)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7224)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7213)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2957)
```

My Notification Received Activity (Error comming in the function- getActivities):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_received);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            users = (Users) bundle.getSerializable("user");
            projectList = (ArrayList<Projects>) bundle.getSerializable("projectlist");
            BASE_URL = bundle.getString("BASE_URL");
            permission = (Permission) bundle.getSerializable("permission");
            projectId = bundle.getString("projectId");
            androidUrl = bundle.getString("androidUrl");
        }

        error_msg = findViewById(R.id.notification_error_msg);
        baseLayout = findViewById(R.id.notificationReceived_baseLayout);
        activityRecycler = findViewById(R.id.notification_recycler);
        activityRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        activityRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        loadingDialog = new Dialog(this);
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loadingdialog_layout);
        Objects.requireNonNull(loadingDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        webservice = new Webservice(BASE_URL, getApplicationContext());

        getActivities();
    }

//This function throws null pointer

    private void getActivities() {
        loadingDialog.show();
        if (activityList != null) {
            activityList.clear();
        }
        activityList = new ArrayList<>();
        String webService = "";
        if (androidUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("qaapproval")) {
            webService = Constants.QA_APPROVAL_LIST;
            type = 1;
        } else if (androidUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("sitepm")) {
            webService = Constants.SITE_APPROVAL_LIST;
            type = 0;
        }

        final String URL = BASE_URL + webService + projectId + "&userid=" + users.getEmployee_id();
        getApprovalList(URL);
    }

    public void getApprovalList(final String APPROVAL_URL) {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(APPROVAL_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Approval URL::: " + APPROVAL_URL);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sitePmActvityList");
                        System.out.println("arraySize:::" + array.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String level = "";
                            String s = object.optString("Approvalstatus", "");
                            if (androidUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("qaapproval"))
                                level = "level 2";
                            else
                                level = "level 1";
                            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
                                ActivityData activityData = new ActivityData();
                                activityData.setActivityDesc(object.getString("ActionDescription"));
                                activityData.setStartDate(object.optString("startdate", ""));
                                activityData.setEndDate(object.optString("enddate", ""));
                                activityData.setProgramGroup(object.getString("programgroup"));
                                activityData.setTransName(object.getString("transformation "));
                                activityData.setLeaderName(object.optString("projectleader", ""));
                                activityData.setPlannedquantity(object.optString("planqty", "0"));
                                String a = object.optString("actuaqty", "0");
                                if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                                    activityData.setActualquantity("0");
                                } else {
                                    activityData.setActualquantity(a);
                                }
                                String statusID = object.optString("actionstatusid", "");
                                activityData.setStatusId(statusID);
                                activityData.setSerialNo(object.optString("snoid", ""));
                                activityData.setActivityId(object.optString("programactionid", ""));
                                activityData.setRate(object.optString("rate", "0"));
                                if (androidUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("qaapproval"))
                                    activityData.setLastUpdatedActual(object.optString("sitepmupdatedqty", "0"));
                                else if (androidUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("sitepm"))
                                    activityData.setLastUpdatedActual(object.optString("lastupdatedqty", "0"));
                                activityData.setApprovalStatus(object.optString("Approvalstatus", "0"));
                                activityData.setBalanceQty(object.optString("balanceqty", "0"));
                                activityData.setFollowupId(object.optString("followupid", "0"));
                                activityData.setMonthlyPlanQty(object.optString("monthlyPlanQty", "0"));
                                activityData.setDailyPlanQty(object.optString("dailyPlanQty", "0"));
                                activityData.setMonthlyExecuted(object.optString("monthlyExecuted", "0"));
                                activityData.setPlanTillDate(object.optString("planTillDate", "0"));
                                activityData.setUnit(object.optString("unit", ""));
                                activityData.setWbsCode(object.optString("wbscode", ""));
                                activityData.setLabourCount(object.optString("labourCount", ""));
                                activityData.setLabourManHours(object.optString("manHour", ""));
                                activityData.setDelayReason(object.optString("delayRegion", ""));
                                activityList.add(activityData);
                            } else {
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("ActivitySize:", String.valueOf(activityList.size()));
                        setDAta(activityList);
                    } else {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(baseLayout, "Error loading content!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        snack.getView().setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getColor(R.color.NotStarted));
                    }
                    snack.show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("VolleyError", error.toString());
                Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(baseLayout, "Could not connect to server!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    snack.getView().setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getColor(R.color.NotStarted));
                }
                snack.show();
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(7500,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);
    }

    void setDAta(ArrayList<ActivityData> activityList) {
        if (activityList.size() == 0) {
            activityRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            error_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ApprovalActivityAdapter activityAdapter = new ApprovalActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), activityList, onClickListener, type);
            activityRecycler.setAdapter(activityAdapter);
            activityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Any help would be appreciated!!! Thanks**

Comment: Are your  androidUrl  default value is Null ?

Comment: @Smishjack It is received from Intent, it has not been initialized. Should i initialize it as well? Even though this error is occurring in 1 out of 10 users, i am not ablt to reproduce the error and there seems to be no way in which androidUrl is null.

Comment: the error shows us the exception is in the function getActivities, the error line-no is 163, you can check the error code